# Creating HttpHandler in IIS subdirectory that accepts POST requests from other hosts

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler

I have access to a sub directory on server like `http://root/_pp`. My job is to create a generic http handler in .NET and drop it in `_pp` directory. The said handler should accept `POST` and `OPTIONS` request from external sources like custom code in .NET and java would be calling the handler using `OPTIONS` and `POST` requests.

I have uploaded quite a simple handler in the sub directory. The code looks like the following

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context){
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                //string origin = context.Request.Headers["Origin"];
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
                //string requestHeaders = context.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"];
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("Hello World again again");
}
```

When I upload this handler to the `_pp` sub directory and send a `POST` or `OPTIONS` request from fiddler, it returns `500 Internal Server Error`.
Please Note: I have no control over configuring the IIS on server, nor can I access anything in `root` directory of the server.

Is it possible to achieve what I want with given constraints? Please help

**EDIT 1** handler registration in `web.config` of `_pp`

```
<system.webserver>
<handlers>
        <add name="IPN" verb="*" path="IPN.ashx" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: However, I can put `web.config` in `_pp` subdirectory

Comment: How is this handler registered in web.config?